# Array is not being updated in useState?

Tags: reactjs

I am aware that its a duplicated question. Other questions didn't solve my problem.

here is the code:

```
const [roles, setRoles] = useState([]);
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GetRoles);
useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
        const rolesArray = data.roles.map(role => { return { value: role.name, id: role.id } });
        setRoles([...rolesArray]);
    }
}, [loading, data]);
```

roles doesn't update. What am I missing?

Value of loading is `true`or `false`
Value of data is:
`{roles:[{id: "1", name: "technical admin"}, {id: "2", name: "admin"}]}`

Comment: Please elaborate more on what the expected vs actual behavior is. Along with the contents of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```js
setRoles(prevRoles => [prevRoles, ...rolesArray])
```

maybe that could be the problem, otherwise please also paste the values for
loading, error, and data

Answer (score 0):

```
// you can use this
setRoles(rolesArray)
// instead of this
setRoles([...rolesArray])
// as you completely overwrite the array
```

But it is just about style. As for your question, if you 100% sure everything inside useEffect works fine then there is only the one answer - the hook gonna work only when 'loading' or 'data' is changed. If it doesn't - there is no change.